# jQuery Event Binding

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins

I'm struggling to get my head around the way I author (and attach to events) in a custom jQuery plugin.

I have the start of a plugin, in this simple example....

[http://jsfiddle.net/ETFairfax/mRAHF/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/ETFairfax/mRAHF/10/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugIn = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            'width': 200,
            'url': 'www.someurl.com'
        };
        // If options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        function somePrivateFunction() {
            return options.url;
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).text(somePrivateFunction());
            $(this).width(options.width);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#testDiv1').myPlugIn({
        'width': 150
    });
    $('#testDiv2').myPlugIn({
        'url': 'www.google.com'
    });
});
```

---

```
<div id="eventDriver1">Click here to update 1</div>
<div id="eventDriver2">Click here to update 2</div>
<div id="testDiv1" class="testClass"></div>
<div id="testDiv2" class="testClass"></div>
```

As you can see I set testDiv1, and testDiv2, and they behave as I'd expect.

Now I want to be able to say that eventDriver1 should refresh testDiv1, and for it to  specify what text shoudl go into it. I just don't know where to start!!

I appreciate that will have been documented somewhere, and/or asked already, but I'm just not sure what buzzwords I need to search for!!! Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Binding events in jQuery is accomplished with `.bind()` or `.live()` or by using one of the shortcuts (such as `.click()`, `.submit()`, `.load()`, etc). I'm not really sure what your question is...

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRAHF/12/)**

```
$('#eventDriver1').click(function() {
    $('#testDiv1').myPlugIn({'url': 'www.yahoo.com'});
});
$('#eventDriver2').click(function() {
    $('#testDiv2').myPlugIn({'url': 'www.microsoft.com', 'width': 250});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, and although it works just fine, and I'm happy to use that method if its the way to do it, but I'm trying to work out how to expose some sort of Update() method on the plugin, and how to call it.  Maybe I have the wrong idea of how things tie together?

Answer (score 1):

Use click.

```
$('#eventDriver1').click(function(){/*do something*/})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's the /* Do Something */ bit that I am confused about. I'm trying to work out how to expose some sort of Update() method on the plugin, and how to call it? Does that make sense?